# How to grant access to an Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

How do I grant access to a script I've made to another G Suite user in my domain please?

Here is the script:

```
function rangeShort() {
  var range = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveRange(),
  data = range.getValues();
  var output = [];
  for(var i = 0, iLen = data.length; i < iLen; i++) {
    var url = UrlShortener.Url.insert({longUrl: data[i][0]});
    output.push([url.id]);
    Utilities.sleep(100);
  }
  range.offset(0,1).setValues(output);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[Here's how to collaborate on your apps script project with other developers.](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/collaborating)

You just have to press the giant "share" button on the top right of the apps script screen. If it isn't there, the script is probably attached to a sheet or form or something, in which case anyone with editing access to that file can view and edit the script.

Answer (score -1):

Try to run that script manually.
https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/standalone#running_a_standalone_script

Then you'll be asked to Review Permissions, review that and grant permissions.

Then you're good to go.
This is a one-time process.